# opendrawer() throwing null pointer error in drawerlayout

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am new on Android.
Through this simple program I want to to open a drawer using button onclick().But This gives null exception error.I tried the solution by googling but unfortunately didn't solve it.
This is **onCreate()** method

```
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            navListener();
        }
```

**navListener()**

```
           public void navListener(){


                final DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
                ImageView nav = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.navbarimagebutton);
                nav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    }
                });



            }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <RelativeLayout   
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <include layout="@layout/app_bar" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

**DrawerLayout**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"></ListView>



        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/red">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/navbarimagebutton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/menu"
                />


            <View
                android:id="@+id/homepagefirstview"

                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"></View>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/hometitle"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/search"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: is your drawerLayout in your activity_main.xml if so can you share this file, if not this is the cause of your null pointer

Comment: no @inner_class7 i have added my activity_main and drwaerlayout xml files

Comment: what is app_bar in your xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your Asking your activity to `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

And this file does not include your `DrawerLayout`

you need to do:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout   
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <!-- add an id here since your using RelativeLayout -->
    <include layout="@layout/app_bar" android:id="@+id/app_bar" />

    <!-- include the drawer this way, probably need to add layout_below="@+id/app_bar" or whatever the id is for your app bar -->
    <!-- Uncomment this <include layout="@layout/drawer_layout"/> -->

    <!-- Or simply copy the drawer layout xml and add layout_below="@+id/app_bar" -->
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <!-- main content area -->
        <FrameLayout 
            android:id="@+id/content_area"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

        <!-- Slide out drawer section -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You are running into NullPointerException because your inflated view does not contain this `DrawerLayout` you are referencing

Comment: throwiing java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY.

Comment: @Bam set the drawerlayout width to match_parent, see above

Comment: but I want to limit the width of drawer

Comment: @Bam what you want to do is limit the width of your view inside the drawer panel not the drawer itself, see update above. You are also missing your main content area, the drawer layout has two areas the drawer and a main content view, see edit above

Comment: But I  am confused how it;s opened since written code in mainactivity  imageclick listener

Comment: @Bam since you have included the app_bar layout in your activity_main layout file via `<include layout="@layout/app_bar" android:id="@+id/app_bar" />` this is perfectly fine, this layout is rendered in the xml hierarchy for that layout so you are able to open and close the drawer from this View's clicks

Comment: but it says No drawer view found with gravity LEFT

Comment: @Bam please share the stack trace for this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100407/discussion-between-bam-and-inner-class7).